# Write a Nested python list into csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have below code to write my nested list into a csv file. The nested list looks like this

```
[['19181011', '13041519', '22121605', '11142007', '23000114'],
['1523141612', '2403051513', '0806022324', '1614012422', '0516121805'],
['23201621', '24171811', '08231524', '16011022', '17131220'],
['2317241822', '2220112421', '1124052211', '1010192318', '2108231524'],
['11220215', '24240507', '19180423', '07081422', '21201224']]
```

```
with open('MLpredictions.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(high5_pred)
```

But when i execute this code, i get like below in the csv file:

```
19181011;13041519;22121605;11142007;23000114
1523141612;2403051513;0806022324;1614012422;0516121805....
```

i changed the delimiter to ',' but then I get 5 different columns.

I want each list to be 1 row separated by ',' and not ';'.

Expected o/p, a single column:

```
19181011,13041519,22121605,11142007,23000114
1523141612,2403051513,0806022324,1614012422,0516121805
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: How do you define "column"?  If you're loading this into Excel, then the output is going to have 5 columns.  After all, in a COMMA-separated file, commas separate the columns.  In other words, you're wrongly complaining about how the data is PRESENTED, not how it is stored.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand this post if it didn't look like a wall of numbers. Consider presenting your data as an example, like `[['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]`

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that there is a specific reason why you want the data all in one column:*

The reason you're getting seperate columns is because you're using the csv format, and your data is not escaped. Your raw file looks like this:

```
19181011,13041519,22121605,11142007,23000114
1523141612,2403051513,0806022324,1614012422,0516121805
```

but you need it to look like this:

```
"19181011,13041519,22121605,11142007,23000114"
"1523141612,2403051513,0806022324,1614012422,0516121805"
```

You're probably best to create a string object for each "row" of your output file. I'd do the following:

```
with open('MLpredictions.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    rows = [','.join([str(number) for number in row]) for row in high5_pred]
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

*Note: unless you have a good reason why you don't want these numbers in different columns, I'd leave your code as is. It will be a lot easier to deal with the native csv format*

Comment: Thank you @Caleb. Your note was well taken and implemented in the suggested format.